# Vim let cursor sit on newline

Tags: vim

Is there a way to let the cursor sit on a newline in Vim, similarly to the default behavior of Emacs?

When you delete a character in the middle of a line, the character gets removed and the cursor now sits on the character that was to its right. If you delete a character at the end of the line however, the character is removed and the cursor now sits on the character that was to its *left*. I would like it to be able to sit on the newline, which is the character (or characters depending on the system) that was to the right of the deleted character. I would also like to be able to have the cursor sit on the newline in general.

Comment: That newline characters are treated specially is the one thing that annoys me most when using vim! In my opinion, this is very un-vimlike, as my actions now have to depend on where in the line the cursor is (e.g., I cannot use `i` to insert a character at the end of the line, but I have to use `a` *and* `i` depending on the situation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with the `virtualedit` setting. Try e.g.
`:set virtualedit=onemore` and read more of it at `:h 'virtualedit'`
Note, this might break plugins or other slightly less tested corners in Vim.

If you also want to make `x` delete the final newline in this mode, you might be able to map `x` to do something more clever, e.g.

`:nnoremap <expr> x col('$')==col('.')?'gJ':'x'`

This basically maps `x` to an expression, that checks, whether the cursor is on the last character (the newline) of the line, and if it is, it will be mapped to the `gJ` command otherwise a normal `x` will be performed.

(Note: not very thoroughly tested, there might be some edge cases)

Comment: This is very close to what I want, and answers what I actually asked. Is there any way to make it so I can actually delete the newline character when the cursor is over it and I press `x` or similar? Basically, I'd like Vim to treat the newline like a normal character, which I suppose would have been a better way to state my original question.

Comment: not that I know of. You might however be able to map x to something. will update the answer

Comment: If you have `:set whichwrap+=h` you might also like `nnoremap <expr> h col('.')==1?'k$l':'h'` so that `h` and `l` behave alike around the linebreak. [edit: does not work if there is an empty line before]